# Is there some default password for a new user in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, users, password

I am a Windows user gradually moving towards Linux. In Windows we have an option of either having or not having some password for a user. Once we do not put a password we can directly log in to the system.

However, in Linux this is not possible as every user must have a password. Even if one does not give a password not typing anything and simply pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> key doesn't log one in (unlike Windows). Is there some default password set for every user or any other mechanism by means of which a password is always assigned?

Comment: password are not mandatory in unix linux system

Comment: Kiwy said it before. Look here for autologin: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=autologin+inittab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authentication can be handled in many different ways in Linux. Password authentication via `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` is the usual default. There is no default password.

A user is not required to have a password. In a typical setup a user without a password will be unable to authenticate with the use of a password. This is common for system users which are used to run daemons, but are not intended to be used directly by a human.

You can configure Linux to allow login to the desktop automatically, or allow login without a password. Authentication is done via [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module), which is highly configurable. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Passwordless_login) offers the following PAM configuration for login without a password:

> If you want to bypass the password prompt in GDM then simply add the
> following line on the first line of /etc/pam.d/gdm-password:

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
```

> Then, add the group `nopasswdlogin` to your system. See Groups for
> group descriptions and group management commands. Now, add your
> user to the `nopasswdlogin` group and you will only have to click
> on your username to login.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the literal question: no, there is no default password. Usually by default an account will have an "invalid" password, that is, a password hash that will not be matched by any password at all. In order to be able to log in, a password must be explicitly specified, e.g. by running `passwd` for the account in question.

However, you can configure the logon manager to automatically log in as a specific user, either immediately or after a delay, if you wish to do so. That is not normally done, but the feature exists.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. For every single user you create in the GUI you have to set manually the password. Blank passwords or default standard password are obviously considered as a high security risk.

## But

You have the command `newusers` witch can help you create one or many users using the default password you want in plain text mode.
usage as root : `newusers file` where *file* is a text file with the folowing structure for each line :
    pw_name:pw_passwd:pw_uid:pw_gid:pw_gecos:pw_dir:pw_shell

You can do it also in one command line. Example :

```
echo chinmay:clearpassword::::/home/maleki:/bin/bash | sudo newusers
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no default password: either an account has a password, or it doesn't (in which case you can't log in, at least not with password authentication). However, you *can* set an empty password. Many services reject empty passwords, though. In particular, with an empty password, you won't be able to log in remotely. But you will be able to log in on the console.

Rather than use this feature, I recommend setting a reasonably strong password, and if you really don't want to have to type it because your computer stays at home and nobody but you accesses it, set up [autologin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin). A passwordless account does make sense in some cases, such as children.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a default password for users. The information you might want to read is the manual page for adduser

`man adduser`

This command uses `useradd` which is a lower level command.

Comment: That depends on the distro. In Debian `adduser` is it's own command. In RHEL, it's a symlink to `useradd`.